# Kraken API Request-sent exception

Tags: python, api, exception

After a simple query

```
k.query_public('Ticker', {'pair' : 'GNOETH'})['result']['GNOETH']['b'][0])
```

if I'm getting a time-out or other exception like 504, the
next query and all next queries in my cycle are getting this exception:

```
http.client.CannotSendRequest: Request-sent
```

How can I prevent this?

Comment: I have the same issue, no answer ?

Comment: I have opened an issue here https://github.com/veox/python3-krakenex/issues/32

Answer (score 3):

I've got an answer - you have to close a connection with k.conn.close() in exception:

```
 while True:
  try:
   trades = k.query_public('Trades', {'pair' : 'ETHUSD'})
   return trades
   break
  except Exception as ex:
   k.conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try also to ensure that the value of "nonce" is set to 0 at the api-key creation.